# Images dont anti-aliase using canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm trying to display an image .png using canvas but, for some reason I can't get it to work, the images are not anti-aliased. That makes it all pixaleted on curves or diagonals.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Pixmap button = g.newPixmap("button.png");


@Override
public Pixmap newPixmap(String fileName) {
  Config config = Config.ARGB_8888;

  Options options = new Options();
  options.inPreferredConfig = config;

  InputStream in = null;
  Bitmap bitmap = null;
  try {
    in = manager.open(fileName);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
    if (bitmap == null)
      throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from asset '" + fileName + "'");
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from asset '" + fileName + "'");
  } finally {
    if (in != null) {
      try {
        in.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
      }
    }
  }

  return new Pixmap(bitmap);
}

g.drawPixmap(button);

@Override
public void drawPixmap(Pixmap pixmap) {
  srcRect = new Rect(0, 0, pixmap.getOriginalWidth(), pixmap.getOriginalHeight());
  dstRect = new Rect(pixmap.getX(), pixmap.getY(), pixmap.getX() + pixmap.getVirtualWidth(), pixmap.getY() + pixmap.getVirtualHeight());
  canvas.drawBitmap(pixmap.bitmap, srcRect, dstRect, paint); 
}
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
paint.setDither(true);
```

Or:

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
```

Comment: That in fact made my images display better but it still show some pixelated curves (less but it still shows). Could that be some design problem (maybe some technique in Photoshop that I should use, or so..) or is there any setting that I should activate?

Comment: Uhm... is the resolution of the images suitable for the device? are you using the hdpi, xhdpi drawable folders?

Comment: Yes, I'm using big resolution for highres devices and I'm using drawable folders

Comment: Then I can't help you more... Let's see if someone else has a better advice.